# Adding a block to a specific location

Tags: layout, blocks, custom-block

I'm trying to insert a block that shows up at a specific point in my page. I created a new layout file, which looks like this:

mylayout.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" after="-" name="my.block" template="my_dir/myblock.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This successfully displays the html content in myblock.phtml, at the **top** of my content block. How can I make this block render **after** another block, such as this one:

catalog.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

Intuitively, I thought this would work, but didn't:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <!--in config file / Istockphp\Customerpage\Block\Customer.php-->
        <block type="core/template" after="product.info.addtocart" name="product.reward" template="socilogica/product_reward.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

### Auto render child blocks for Mage_Core_Block_Text_List

As per as magento,a block is automatically rendered when it  `parent block` class is `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List`.

On first xml code ,you have put `<block type="core/template" after="-" name="my.block" template="my_dir/myblock.phtml" />`  as child block of block content.

**see at page.xml**

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>
```

As `content` block type is `core/text_list` that means it block  class `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List`.So `my.block` automatically rendered.

### Render child block by $this->getChildHtml()

But in second xml code,block  name is `product.info`,which is `block type` is `catalog/product_view` which  block class is not `core/text_list`.This block class Mage_Catalog_Block_View.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

**So,if you want to rendered  it child block automatically then it not possible** without call  `all child Blocks` by using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml()?>`

Or ,specific child block using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(cHilblockname)?>` .

As on `view.phtml` it all child blocks are not by rendere `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml()?>` and each child block render individual call

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('childblockname')?>` then you need  add

```
<?php $this->getChildHtml('product.reward');> at view.phtml
```

Comment: thank you Amit. How would I be able to render my block **after** the product.info.addtocart block? When I render my block with the code above, my output displays at the bottom of the page, after the footer.